# ServiceNow Rest API Timefield

Tags: rest, pagination, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to write a Rest API client where ServiceNow Database will be polled every 10 minutes to get the Data. 
Below is the Url that I built:
"https://servicenowinstance.com/api/now/table/employee_table?sysparm_limit=200&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_query=sys_created_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2018-02-28','14:23:40')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2018-02-28','15:17:04')^ORDERBYsys_created_on".

After implementing Pagination I am starting the Incremental Load. Where I poll every 10 minutes to get the New Data. So in the above URL I get the  BETWEEN . So I will get the Data which satisfies the Between Condition.
My Question is that the VM machine I use maintains UTC time. And I am not sure which Timezone does the ServiceNow Tables use to store the Data.

In short my question is what Timezone does ServiceNow use to store its Sys_created Field. Is it same as UTC or is it different?

Answer (score 0):

The database stores dates and times as UTC ([KB0534905](https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0534905)), but depending on how you pull data via REST, it may return in the timezone of the user account being used for authentication.

Take a look at [Table API GET](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=jakarta&id=r_TableAPI-GET), in particular the `sysparm_display_value` field.

> Data retrieval operation for reference and choice fields. Based on
>   this value, retrieves the display value and/or the actual value from
>   the database.
>
> - **true** returns display values for all fields.
> - **false** returns actual values from the database. If a value is not specified, this parameter defaults to **false**.
> - **all** returns both actual and display values.

In your case since you're not setting that parameter, it should be in UTC.